# how to find the PHP folder when configure one software?

Tags: php

When I want build-mapserver with php/mapscrit module, I should use the
 `./configure --with-php= ../php-4.3.11`(the dir of PHP), but I do not know the PHP dir on my OS.

I `apt-get install` the PHP and I `locate php` on the shell but I seem to get an unrelated result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you can search for folders and files with the `locate` command:

```
locate php5
```

will print out lots of paths containing php - the "php folder" itself should be the /usr/lib/php5 folder.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Dqgv4r4m, should be which one as the output?

Comment: - DIR should be the location of the PHP4 or PHP5 distribution (source or dev
  package).  The module may work with older versions of PHP (4.1.x or 4.2.x), but 
  PHP 4.3.x is strongly recommended. The configure script should 
  automatically detect which version of PHP you are attempting to build 
  with and take the necessary actions.

    e.g.  $ ./configure --with-php=../php-4.3.11, Is the /usr/lib/php5 folder right?

Comment: yes, as per your pastebin snipplet its /usr/lib/php5, so --with-php=/usr/lib/php5 is right.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know your php installation path then hit command `which php` it will show you bin directory.